# az devops login Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, az

I've installed AZ DEVOPS extension from az cli

```
  az extension add --name azure-devops
  az devops login --organization https://myorg.com
```

But when I insert my DEVOPS Personal Access Token, fail with the following error.
Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage.
You can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout.
Refer https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on sign in with PAT.

I'm trying to access from a Linux Centos 7 machine to automate DevOps Pipeline creation.
Someone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a  prerequisite,your **Azure CLI version must be 2.0.49** at a minimum. You can use `az --version` to validate.

After you add az extension, you could also run `az login` to sign in.

> If you have already signed in with az login interactively or using
>   user name and password, then you don't have to provide a token as az
>   devops commands now support sign in through az login.

When you are using az devops login command, first make sure you are using Azure DevOps Service organization URL. Example: `https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganizationName`.  Azure DevOps Server/TFS is not support at present.

For Azure DevOps tokens, you need to make sure it's valid and with  enough  scopes for this token to authorize for your specific tasks.

More details please refer our official tutorial here-- [Sign in with a Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Yes It worked. Because I was running a script, I forgot I was already using az login.