# Az CLI commands in Azure DevOps pipeline not working as expected

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-repos

I want to check the statuses of pull requests in a pipeline, then add them to an array if their status is 'abandoned'. **However, the documented solutions for running Az CLI commands in ADO Pipelines are not working as expected for me.**

For example, I have the following lines in an Azure CLI task:

```
echo "$(System.AccessToken)" | az devops login

az repos pr show --id xxxx
```

This results in the following warnings, then error:

```
WARNING: Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage.
WARNING: You can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout.
WARNING: Refer https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on sign in with PAT.

TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as ... in a web browser to enable access to the service.
```

**EDIT:** months later it occurred to me that I could look up the ID from the above error in Azure AD, and it returns a particular Enterprise Application. With that, I really can't make sense of the error..

**I've tried a few different things:**

1. Using a bash or powershell script with the PAT as an 'ENV' variable, instead of the Azure CLI task:

   ```
     - bash
         az repos pr......
       env:
       AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
   ```

   - This seems to get around the authentication issue, however, using this method the results of `az repos pr` commands are totally unexpected:

     - `az repos pr show --id xxxx` returns "*ERROR: TF401180: The requested pull request was not found.*", even though the PR number certainly exists. I can confirm this in Azure DevOps or by running the command in my local Powershell or Ubuntu CLI.
     - `az repos pr list --status abandoned --top 10` only returns one very old PR, but if I run this locally it returns 10 of the most recent abandoned PRs.
     - I am using the following to make sure I am connected to the correct ADO organization and project:

       ```
       az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/correctorg
       az devops configure --defaults project=correctProject
       az devops configure --list
       ```
2. The solution posted here: [Azure Pipelines error "TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as: ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75536144/azure-pipelines-error-tf401444-please-sign-in-at-least-once-as)

   - This made no difference.
3. Using a personal PAT instead of the System.AccessToken one.

   - This made no difference
4. Different VM images (Ubuntu-latest, Ubuntu 20.04, Windows-latest)

   - This made no difference

Comment: Which version of Azure CLI are you using?  Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086877/az-devops-login-failed-to-store-pat-using-keyring-falling-back-to-file-storage

Comment: Az CLI v 2.52.0. Apparently it is up to date. I've already tried everything mentioned in that question/answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is just a typo but you missed double quote

```
echo "$(System.AccessToken)" | az devops login

az repos pr show --id xxxx
```

I tried this and I got proper response.

I just run:

```
steps:
  - bash:
      az repos pr show --id 14
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

nad I got proper reply

```
{
  "artifactId": "vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/4fa6b279-3db9-4cb0-aab8-e06c2ad550b2%2f1eb083aa-2de7-478c-ac8b-8a0879d6d652%2f14",
  "autoCompleteSetBy": null,
  "closedBy": null,
  "closedDate": null,
  "codeReviewId": 14,
  "commits": null,
  "completionOptions": null,
  "completionQueueTime": null,
...
```

Comment: Sorry, just a typo - just reviewed my code and it's not missing the double quotes and I tested it again just to be sure. I've edited my post to correct that. Thanks for testing!

Comment: @log1co Can you pls accept this as answer then?

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear - the issue is still occurring. I made a typo in my question/post (which I edited to fix), and that's what this answer was essentially pointing out. My actual code is the same as in this answer and it's still not working as expected.

Comment: Where do you host repositories? GitHub or Azure Repos? If Azure Repos do you want to reach the same organization/project as your pipeline is hosted.

Comment: Azure repos. And that's correct, the pipeline as well as repos are all in the same org/project. Just to be sure I set the org/project via az devops configure commands and verify using the list command.

Comment: At this point I think the weirdest part about this is the TF401444 error. When I search it online, most resolve it by using the PAT to login, but in my case I'm getting it when I use the PAT to login. It asks me to "sign in as" xxxxxxxxxxxxx id which is the id of the Enterprise Application tied to the Service Principal used for the Service Connection for my AzCLI@2 task. It has contributor role at the subscription level and it gets used regularly in other pipelines' tasks.

Comment: Could you skip `az devops configure`? I don't use it since I host and run pipeline in organization/project I want to read from.

Comment: I removed `az devops configure` lines, as well as `--organization` in the `az devops login` command, that resulted in "pull request not found". So I added `--organization` back to `az devops login` and I get the same TF401444 error again.

I even tried removing the `az devops login` completely and I still get the same TF401444 error